# JsPrintSetup Firefox plugin custom page size

Tags: firefox, printing

I am trying to print bills in my web application, a user would print bills from a web browser. It doesn't need to be compatible with other browsers, its okay if it only works in firefox. The problem that I encountered was paper overflow, the printer, despite of size of text and content printed everything in A4 or letter paper. I tried using JsPrintSetup plugin for firefox to control this by changing the paper size. The plugin works fine but I need to use custom size of paper, and I need to change the height of paper dynamically. But no matter what I do, the printer prints everything in same paper size, it does not prints on the custom paper I define. So, if anyone has worked with this plugin, please help me with this.

Comment: I have worked with this plugin and I have achieved what you need. Do you still need to know how to do it?